# How can I convert a JavaScript variable to a Java variable?

Tags: java, javascript

I need to convert a variable from JavaScript into a Java variable. I'm asking users for their e-mail ids with a Block-UI popup through Test Box. If the field is neither null nor empty, the e-mail id should be sent to a session variable so that it can be accessed anywhere in the project.

Here's my code:

```
function sbtEmail(){
    var email = document.getElementById("EmailId").value;
    if (email == null || email == ""){
        alert("Enter your contact Email address to continue...!");
        document.getElementById("EmailId").focus();
    } else {
        <%session.setAttribute("quoteEmail",email);%>
        window.location.href = "demo2.jsp";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to submit the form or send an XMLHTTPRequest over the wire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved : using Ajax will solve the Problem.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    function sbtEmail(){
        var email = document.getElementById("anonymousEmailId").value;
        if (email==null||email==""){
            alert("Enter your contact Email address to continue...!");
            document.getElementById("anonymousEmailId").focus();
        }else{
            enqueue("demo1.jsp?Id="+email,ajaxReplay);
        }
    }
    function ajaxReplay(){
        window.location.href="demo.jsp";
    }
    </script>
```

In demo1.jsp : set value for session variable

```
String Email = request.getParameter("Id");
session.setAttribute("sessEmail",Email);
```

Comment: Please reference your ajax.js library and where to get it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was talking about, by the way. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not set a variable in the session (which resides on the server alone!) directly from JavaScript. You have to pass them to your server in some kind of request, and then the server can set it in the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this Ajax file:----> eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, r) { e = function(c) { return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36)) }; if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) { while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c); k = [function(e) { return r[e] } ]; e = function() { return '\\w+' }; c = 1 }; while (c--) if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]); return p } ('d 7;f n(a,b,c){6(!7)7=j s;6(!7.n(a,b,c))g l;6(!7.k)7.o();g h}f s(){3.5=j t();3.8=9;3.k;3.m=h;3.n=f(a,b,c){u(d i=0;i<3.5.p;i++)6(3.5[i][0]==a&&3.5[i][1]==b&&3.5[i][2]==c)g l;6(3.8==9){3.k=l;3.m=h;3.8=0}v{++3.8}3.5[3.8]=j t();3.5[3.8][0]=a;3.5[3.8][1]=b;3.5[3.8][2]=c;6(3.k&&c)w(c);g h};3.o=f(){6(3.8==9||3.5.p==0)g;3.k=h;6(3.m){d r=q();d a;6(r){u(d i=0;i<3.5.p;i++){6(3.5[i][2])w(3.5[i][2])}}3.m=l}3.x(3.5[0][0],3.5[0][1])};3.x=f(a,b){d r=q();6(r){r.E("F",a,h);r.G=f(){6(r.H==4){6(b)b(r.I);7.5.J(0,1);7.8>0?--7.8:7.8=9;6(7.8==9){7.k=l;7.m=h;g}v{7.o()}}};r.K(9)}}}f q(){d A=9;y{A=j z("L.B")}C(e){y{A=j z("M.B")}C(N){A=9}}6(!A&&O D!="P"){A=j D()}g A}', 52, 52, '|||this||queue|if|g_q|position|null||||var||function|return|true||new|isProcessing|false|callPreFunctions|enqueue|process|length|getXMLHTTP||ajaxQueue|Array|for|else|eval|getAjaxQueueResult|try|ActiveXObject||XMLHTTP|catch|XMLHttpRequest|open|GET|onreadystatechange|readyState|responseText|splice|send|Msxml2|Microsoft|oc|typeof|undefined'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```